# Show 0.00 as comparison of NONE in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a variable `value.discount_total` in this value executes

```
None
```

But when I place a order..In Order email I want to Show 0.00 not NONE for this value .How could I do this ?

Comment: If you give downvote, consider adding a comment to help the OP and others to understand the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smarter approach will be to make `discount_total` as `DecimalField` field model, and gave it `0.00` as `default` value, In this way you don't have to check to if `discount_total` is None in templates or any other places that you need to use it.

Here's an example:

```
discount_total = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=Decimal('0.00')
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default) `{{value.discount_total|default:'0.00'}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try `|default` filter as

```
{{value.discount_total|default:"0.00"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the initial value of `value.discount_total = 0.` in the views.py of your Django app, instead of setting it in the template.